# How to slow down my CPU?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, cpu

I have [Vaio Z-690](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Vaio_Z_series#Models) laptop, and its processor speed is 2.66 GHz. I don't need too much speed, and I'm OK with 2 GHz or even less. Just for browsing websites it's enough.

I want to slow down my CPU to make it more silent. The fan is a bit noisy now. Is there a way to do this in Windows 7 64-bit?

The *Notebook Hardware Control* software doesn't run on 64-bit systems. And I don't know what to do. Also, there aren't any BIOS settings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried using the built-in power options in Windows 7? I think this is achievable by choosing a passive cooling strategy.:

1. If you hover your mouse over the little power icon in the activity bar, you should see this: [image: Hover]
2. Click "More power options", and this window is shown: [image: More power options]
3. Choose "Change plan settings" to get here:[image: Plan settings]
4. You should find what you're looking for under "Change advanced power settings":[image: Advanced]
   The tooltip is from hovering over "Plugged in: Active". If you hover over "On battery: Passive" you see the text **Slow the processor before increasing fan speed**, which sounds like what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If necessary to use often for the specific exe, here is PowerShell power plan switch (ensure your power plan matches SCHEME_BALANCED):

LimitCPU.bat:

```
powershell.exe -NoExit -File "LimitCPU.ps1"
```

LimitCPU.ps1:

```
$ExeToLimit = "*.EXE"


function Limit-CPU ([int]$Percent)
    {
    Write-Host "CPU "$Percent"%"
    powercfg.exe -setacvalueindex SCHEME_BALANCED SUB_PROCESSOR PROCTHROTTLEMAX $Percent
    powercfg -SetActive SCHEME_BALANCED
    }


Limit-CPU 20
Start-Process -FilePath $ExeToLimit
Pause
Limit-CPU 100
```